# Mustache function arguments and javascript

Tags: javascript, mustache

Peace of mustache template:

```
        <span class="frameSpec blackBg">{{#i18n}}Kids{{/i18n}}</span>
```

Peace of javascript code:

```
// Preparing data to view
var items = {
            'items': data.matches,
            'i18n' : function(){
               return get_translation(key);
             }
            };
        //--

$("#items").append(Mustache.render(items_template, items));
```

This doesn't work, key always is undefinded?

Comment: Where does `key` come from? It's not mentioned anywhere else in your code other than when trying to call the `get_translation` function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [calling function with arguments in mustache javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045165/calling-function-with-arguments-in-mustache-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the fix for my code:

```
// Preparing data to view
var items = {
    'items': data.matches,
    'i18n' : function(){
        return function(key){
            return get_translation(key);
        }
     }
};
//--
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should type the function like that:

```
'i18n' : function(key) {
   return get_translation(key);
}
```

I.e. the `key` variable is not defined and probably is passed as a parameter of your function.