# Variable variable names in Mustache , e.g. {{{{display_field_name}}}}

Tags: javascript, mustache

This may be considered an additional question to this
[calling function with arguments in mustache javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045165/calling-function-with-arguments-in-mustache-javascript)

My problem is I want to go something like

```
{{{{display_field_name}}}}
```

And for display_field_name to be resolved, lets say to "description", and  then

```
{{description}}
```

is then resolved.

I can do this like this, but it's not very elegant template code.

```
{{#resolve}}{{display_field_name}}{{/resolve}}
```

Which is done by adding this 'resolve' function to the current context

```
        resolve:function(){
            return function(text,render){
                return render("{{" + render(text) + "}}");
            };
        },
```

i.e. just add that to whatever hash/object you pass to Mustache.

Is there a better way of doing this ?.