# "If logic" based on function output in mustache.js

Tags: javascript, mustache

Based on [How do I accomplish an if/else in mustache.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027525/how-do-i-accomplish-an-if-else-in-mustache-js) and [calling function with arguments in mustache javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045165/calling-function-with-arguments-in-mustache-javascript), I know I can create conditionals in mustache.js templates and also invoke functions to print something on my rendered HTML.

But can they both be combined ? That is, can we "if" the result of a function ?

In pseudo-code:

```
If someFunction(args){ 
    // print something
}
```

With mustache.js notation:

```
{{#someFunction}}someValue{{/someFunction}}
```

This would output the result of the evaluation of someFunction. Can we print only if the function's evaluation is positive ?

I know about the "logic-less templating", but a developer's gotta do what a developer's gotta do.

Answer (score 0):

You need your function to return a value, and then evaluate that value within your if-statement. This is the general logic as below...

```
function returnBool(b){
   return b;
}

if (returnBool(true) === true){
  mustache.render();
}
```